# Does MCU RAM size affect quality of WAV read from SD?

Tags: microcontroller, audio, attiny, sd, sram

I'm planning to build a cheap and compact WAV audio player that reads audio from a microSD card using Petit-FatFs. The Petit-FatFs driver is designed for use with devices with less than 512B RAM. My idea was to use an ATtiny X5 series MCU, but there are three variants:

- ATtiny25 - 2kB flash, 128B SRAM
- ATtiny45 - 4kB flash, 256B SRAM
- ATtiny85 - 8kB flash, 512B SRAM

The firmware does not occupy more than 2kB.
But does the RAM size affect the audio quality? I don't want more RAM than necessary.

Comment: Why do you think it would affect audio quality?

Comment: Because the RAM is not big enough to store an entire tune, and I thought that it might cause some kind of lag or loss. I do not know much about RAM nor audio.

Comment: A while ago I ordered ATtiny85, because they were cheaper than 25 and 45. I don't care about unused resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if a buffer underrun occurs, which will result in a "hiccup" in audio playback. This happens when the current audio in RAM finishes playing before new audio can be read from the medium. There isn't really a good solution for this other than to use faster media or access methods or to arrange the data on the medium in a layout optimized for the application.

Comment: Another solution is more RAM / buffering, the more you have the the more can go wrong before the buffer under-runs.

Comment: If you're not double-/ring-buffering in the first place then it can't get right to begin with.